# Tikz: positionning a \begin{scope}...\end{scope} relatively to the left of another block

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I have two blocks of the form `\begin{scope}...\end{scope}`, and I would like to position the second block at a fixed distance from the rightmost border of the first block (for instance `1cm`). But if you use `xshift = cst` for the second block, you position the second block relatively to the leftmost border of the first block. Is there an easy way to do that ?

> > Here is the comment regarding the suggested similar question with
> >     its two answers:
> >     the first answer does not work for some unknow reason:
> >     the second block get shifted both horizontally and vertically;
> >     the second answer works sometimes, but not always as demonstred
> >     by the following example where (1) the second box is shifted horizontally
> >     and vertically, and the scale is broken (see code and example at the end
> >     of this post

Here is an example where the `xshift` parameter of the second block is adjusted manually (rather than directly setting a distance of `1cm` between the 2 blocks).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

\def\argument#1{\mathtt{#1}}
\def\constraint#1{\textsc{#1}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{scope}[xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm]
\begin{axis}[axis equal image=true,xlabel={nb\_bump\_on\_decreasing\_sequence},
ylabel={nb\_decreasing},
title style={yshift=1.2ex},
title={$\argument{sv}=12$},
xtick ={0,2,...,2},
ytick ={0,2,...,10},
minor tick num=1,
grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!20},
xmin=-1,xmax=4,
ymin=-1,ymax=12,
extra description/.code={
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description1) at (c1) {\large\ding{172}};
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description2) at (c2) {\large\ding{173}};
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description3) at (c3) {\large\ding{174}};
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description4) at (c4) {\large\ding{175}};
}]

\addplot[blue!20,only marks]
    coordinates {(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)(0,4)(0,5)(0,6)(0,7)(0,8)(0,9)(0,10)(0,11)};
\addplot[blue!50,only marks]
    coordinates {(1,4)(1,5)(1,6)(1,7)(1,8)(1,9)(1,10)(2,6)(2,7)(2,8)(2,9)(3,8)};
\addplot[red,only marks]
    coordinates {(1,3)};
\addplot[blue!50,densely dashed]
    coordinates {(0,0)(3,8)(0,11)(0,0)(0,0)};
\draw[fill=pink,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:-1.5,-1) -- (axis cs:5.0,12) -- (axis cs:5.0,12) -- (axis cs:5.0,-1) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick]
    coordinates {(-1.5,-1)(5.0,12)};
\draw[fill=pink,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:-1,4) -- (axis cs:4,4) -- (axis cs:4,-1) -- (axis cs:-1,-1) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick]
    coordinates {(-1,4)(4,4)};
\draw[fill=cyan,opacity=0.2] (axis cs:-1,12.0) -- (axis cs:4,7.0) -- (axis cs:4,12) -- (axis cs:-1,12) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!50,thick]
    coordinates {(-1,12.0)(4,7.0)};
\addplot[orange]
    coordinates {(1,3)(4,3)};
\addplot[orange,only marks,mark=otimes*]
    coordinates {(1,3)};
\addplot[orange,only marks,mark=diamond*]
    coordinates {(2,3)(3,3)};
\coordinate (c1) at (axis cs:4.6,10.0);
\coordinate (c2) at (axis cs:4.6,4);
\coordinate (c3) at (axis cs:4.6,7.0);
\coordinate (c4) at (axis cs:4.6,3);
\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=7cm,yshift=0cm]
\begin{axis}[axis equal image=true,xlabel={nb\_bump\_on\_decreasing\_sequence},
ylabel={nb\_decreasing},
title style={yshift=1.2ex},
title={$\argument{sv}=11$},
xtick ={0,2,...,3},
ytick ={0,2,...,11},
minor tick num=1,
grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!20},
xmin=-1,xmax=3,
ymin=-1,ymax=11,
extra description/.code={
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description1) at (c1) {\large\ding{172}};
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description2) at (c2) {\large\ding{173}};
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description3) at (c3) {\large\ding{174}};
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description4) at (c4) {\large\ding{175}};
}]

\addplot[blue!20,only marks]
    coordinates {(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)(0,4)(0,5)(0,6)(0,7)(0,8)(0,9)(0,10)};
\addplot[blue!50,only marks]
    coordinates {(1,4)(1,5)(1,6)(1,7)(1,8)(1,9)(2,6)(2,7)(2,8)};
\addplot[red,only marks]
    coordinates {(1,3)};
\addplot[blue!50,densely dashed]
    coordinates {(0,0)(2,6)(2,8)(0,10)(0,0)(0,0)};
\draw[fill=pink,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:-1.5,-1) -- (axis cs:4.5,11) -- (axis cs:4.5,11) -- (axis cs:4.5,-1) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick]
    coordinates {(-1.5,-1)(4.5,11)};
\draw[fill=pink,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:-1,4) -- (axis cs:3,4) -- (axis cs:3,-1) -- (axis cs:-1,-1) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick]
    coordinates {(-1,4)(3,4)};
\draw[fill=cyan,opacity=0.2] (axis cs:-1,11.0) -- (axis cs:3,7.0) -- (axis cs:3,11) -- (axis cs:-1,11) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!50,thick]
    coordinates {(-1,11.0)(3,7.0)};
\addplot[orange]
    coordinates {(1,3)(3,3)};
\addplot[orange,only marks,mark=otimes*]
    coordinates {(1,3)};
\addplot[orange,only marks,mark=diamond*]
    coordinates {(2,3)};
\coordinate (c1) at (axis cs:3.55,8.0);
\coordinate (c2) at (axis cs:3.55,4);
\coordinate (c3) at (axis cs:3.55,7.0);
\coordinate (c4) at (axis cs:3.55,3);
\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

> > EXAMPLE THAT DOES NOT WORK WITH SOLUTION SUGGESTED BY THE SIMILAR QUESTION

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\def\argument#1{\mathtt{#1}}
\def\constraint#1{\textsc{#1}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\node(scope1){
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal image=true,xlabel={nb\_bump\_on\_decreasing\_sequence},
ylabel={nb\_dip\_on\_increasing\_sequence},
title style={yshift=1.2ex},
title={$\argument{sv}=12$},
xtick ={0,2,...,2},
ytick ={0,2,...,2},
minor tick num=1,
grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!20},
xmin=-1,xmax=4,
ymin=-1,ymax=4,
extra description/.code={
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description1) at (c1) {\large\ding{172}};
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description2) at (c2) {\large\ding{173}};
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description3) at (c3) {\large\ding{174}};
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description4) at (c4) {\large\ding{175}};
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description5) at (c5) {\large\ding{176}};
}
]

\addplot[blue!20,only marks]
    coordinates {(0, 0)(0, 1)(0, 2)(0, 3)(1, 0)(2, 0)(3, 0)};
\addplot[blue!50,only marks]
    coordinates {(1, 1)};
\addplot[red,only marks]
    coordinates {(1, 2)(2, 1)};
\addplot[blue!50,densely dashed]
    coordinates {(0, 0)(3, 0)(0, 3)(0, 0)(0, 0)};
\draw[fill=pink,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:-1,0.6666666666666666) -- (axis cs:4,2.3333333333333335) -- (axis cs:4,7) -- (axis cs:-1,7) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick]
    coordinates {(-1, 0.6666666666666666)(4, 2.3333333333333335)};
\draw[fill=pink,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:0.6666666666666666,-1) -- (axis cs:2.3333333333333335,4) -- (axis cs:4.0,4) -- (axis cs:4.0,-1) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick]
    coordinates {(0.6666666666666666, -1)(2.3333333333333335, 4)};
\draw[fill=pink,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:-1,3.3333333333333335) -- (axis cs:4,-1.6666666666666667) -- (axis cs:4,10) -- (axis cs:-1,10) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick]
    coordinates {(-1, 3.3333333333333335)(4, -1.6666666666666667)};
\addplot[brown,only marks,mark=otimes*]
    coordinates {(2, 1)};
\addplot[brown,only marks,mark=otimes*]
    coordinates {(1, 2)};
\coordinate (c1) at (axis cs:4.2,2.3333333333333335);
\coordinate (c2) at (axis cs:2.3333333333333335,4.2);
\coordinate (c3) at (axis cs:3.333333333333334,-1.2);
\coordinate (c4) at (axis cs:2.2,1.2);
\coordinate (c5) at (axis cs:1.2,2.2);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
};
\node[at={($(scope1.east)+(1cm,0)$)},anchor=west] (scope2){
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal image=true,xlabel={nb\_bump\_on\_decreasing\_sequence},
ylabel={nb\_dip\_on\_increasing\_sequence},
title style={yshift=1.2ex},
title={$\argument{sv}=11$},
xtick ={0,2,...,3},
ytick ={0,2,...,3},
minor tick num=1,
grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!20},
xmin=-1,xmax=3,
ymin=-1,ymax=3,
extra description/.code={
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description1) at (c1) {\large\ding{172}};
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description2) at (c2) {\large\ding{173}};
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description3) at (c3) {\large\ding{174}};
}
]

\addplot[blue!20,only marks]
    coordinates {(0, 0)(0, 1)(0, 2)(1, 0)(2, 0)};
\addplot[blue!50,only marks]
    coordinates {(1, 1)};
\addplot[blue!50,densely dashed]
    coordinates {(0, 0)(2, 0)(0, 2)(0, 0)(0, 0)};
\draw[fill=pink,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:-1,0.3333333333333333) -- (axis cs:3,1.6666666666666667) -- (axis cs:3,5) -- (axis cs:-1,5) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick]
    coordinates {(-1, 0.3333333333333333)(3, 1.6666666666666667)};
\draw[fill=pink,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:0.3333333333333333,-1) -- (axis cs:1.6666666666666667,3) -- (axis cs:3.0,3) -- (axis cs:3.0,-1) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick]
    coordinates {(0.3333333333333333, -1)(1.6666666666666667, 3)};
\draw[fill=pink,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:-1,3.0) -- (axis cs:3,-1.0) -- (axis cs:3,9) -- (axis cs:-1,9) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick]
    coordinates {(-1, 3.0)(3, -1.0)};
\coordinate (c1) at (axis cs:3.15,1.6666666666666667);
\coordinate (c2) at (axis cs:1.6666666666666667,3.15);
\coordinate (c3) at (axis cs:3.15,-1.0);
\coordinate (c4) at (axis cs:-1,-1);
\coordinate (c5) at (axis cs:-1,-1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

> > HOW TO EXTERNALISE THE PROPOSED SOLUTION?

I did not manange to externalise the figure of the proposed solution,
maybe because of the \sbox or because of the multiple tikzpicture.
I proceed as follows:

1. put the first example in fig1.tex

   \tikzexternalenable\tikzsetnextfilename{ext_fig1}
   \sbox\leftplot{
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
   ...
   {\usebox\rightplot};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \tikzexternaldisable
2. put the second example if fig2.tex
3. create two dummy files file_fig1.tex and file_fig2.tex
4. create a final file file_fig12.tex
5. compile using the following commands:

pdflatex -shell-escape file_fig1.tex

pdflatex -shell-escape file_fig2.tex

pdflatex file_fig12.tex

I got a compilation error, while typing pdflatex -shell-escape file_fig1.tex

> > Now I give fig1.tex fig2.tex file_fig1.tex file_fig2.tex file_fig12.tex
> >     for which the externalisation works (just to say that it works on standard
> >     TikZ figures):

fig1.tex

```
\tikzexternalenable\tikzsetnextfilename{ext_fig1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=pink, draw=black] (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikzexternaldisable
```

fig2.tex

```
\tikzexternalenable\tikzsetnextfilename{ext_fig2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=cyan, draw=black] (0,0) rectangle (2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikzexternaldisable
```

file_fig1.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,external}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newsavebox{\leftplot}
\newsavebox{\rightplot}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
Dummy Document Containing Figure 1 for Getting Externalize TikZ Figures in a Fast Way
\input{fig1.tex}
\end{document}
```

file_fig2.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,external}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newsavebox{\leftplot}
\newsavebox{\rightplot}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
Dummy Document Containing Figure 2 for Getting Externalize TikZ Figures in a Fast Way
\input{fig2.tex}
\end{document}
```

file_fig12.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,external}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newsavebox{\leftplot}
\newsavebox{\rightplot}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\tikzexternaldisable % by default disable

The first figure.

\input fig1.tex

The second figure

\input fig2.tex

\end{document}
```

Comment: @BambOo Even though I suspect that a solution using `local bounding box` may be possible, I do not think that this question is a duplicate of the question you link. Rather, it is a nontrivial extension  (IMHO) and would therefore vote against closing this question as a duplicate (which you did not suggest, but others may want to do seeing this link).

Comment: @marmot I think I see what you mean, but then I guess the title and the beginning of the post do not agree ("relatively to the left" and "from the rightmost border" ) ,  right ? Also, I think I do not really get what the OP wants... I mean does he need an automatic way of placing two `scope` relatively to one another ?

Comment: @BambOo I think the OP wants to achieve the current output in a more suggestive way, and I think this is a very nice question and deserves a good answer. As the OP clarifies in his update, `local bounding box` does not work per se. I think one could rephrase his question as :  " How can one position scopes with the same methods as one can position nodes?". That is, one may want to put one scope `right=2cm of` another scope. The OP's example is complex enough such that a simple `path picture` cheat does not work (at least for me).

Comment: @marmot Ok now that's clearer to me. Thanks for the edit Nicolas Beldiceanu

Comment: @marmot Looking back at it, I agree with you this is an interesting question. I actually wondered how to do this too, but always stumbled upon the previous solutions. My apologies for the misjudgment.

Comment: Please don't edit questions in ways which invalidate existing answers. Although you haven't removed the original question, you have added a second question. Not only does this render the existing answer retrospectively incomplete. It also violates the one-question-per-question rule. I can answer the second question, but I'm not going to further muddy the waters here by doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not really found a nice solution. But I have a proposal that at first sight nests `tikzpicture`s. Well, it does nest `tikzpicture`s, but in a safe way, I think. Let us recall why one should avoid nesting `tikzpicture`s first: some options/directives of the ambient `tikzpicture` may screw up the embedded ones. However, as far as I can tell, this does not happen if one stores the `tikzpicture`s in `\savebox`es, and this is what I'm doing in this proposal.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newsavebox{\leftplot}
\newsavebox{\rightplot}
\begin{document}

\def\argument#1{\mathtt{#1}}
\def\constraint#1{\textsc{#1}}

\sbox\leftplot{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{axis}[axis equal image=true,xlabel={nb\_bump\_on\_decreasing\_sequence},
ylabel={nb\_decreasing},
title style={yshift=1.2ex},
title={$\argument{sv}=12$},
xtick ={0,2,...,2},
ytick ={0,2,...,10},
minor tick num=1,
grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!20},
xmin=-1,xmax=4,
ymin=-1,ymax=12,
extra description/.code={
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description1) at (c1) {\large\ding{172}};
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description2) at (c2) {\large\ding{173}};
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description3) at (c3) {\large\ding{174}};
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description4) at (c4) {\large\ding{175}};
}]

\addplot[blue!20,only marks]
    coordinates {(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)(0,4)(0,5)(0,6)(0,7)(0,8)(0,9)(0,10)(0,11)};
\addplot[blue!50,only marks]
    coordinates {(1,4)(1,5)(1,6)(1,7)(1,8)(1,9)(1,10)(2,6)(2,7)(2,8)(2,9)(3,8)};
\addplot[red,only marks]
    coordinates {(1,3)};
\addplot[blue!50,densely dashed]
    coordinates {(0,0)(3,8)(0,11)(0,0)(0,0)};
\draw[fill=pink,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:-1.5,-1) -- (axis cs:5.0,12) -- (axis cs:5.0,12) -- (axis cs:5.0,-1) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick]
    coordinates {(-1.5,-1)(5.0,12)};
\draw[fill=pink,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:-1,4) -- (axis cs:4,4) -- (axis cs:4,-1) -- (axis cs:-1,-1) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick]
    coordinates {(-1,4)(4,4)};
\draw[fill=cyan,opacity=0.2] (axis cs:-1,12.0) -- (axis cs:4,7.0) -- (axis cs:4,12) -- (axis cs:-1,12) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!50,thick]
    coordinates {(-1,12.0)(4,7.0)};
\addplot[orange]
    coordinates {(1,3)(4,3)};
\addplot[orange,only marks,mark=otimes*]
    coordinates {(1,3)};
\addplot[orange,only marks,mark=diamond*]
    coordinates {(2,3)(3,3)};
\coordinate (c1) at (axis cs:4.6,10.0);
\coordinate (c2) at (axis cs:4.6,4);
\coordinate (c3) at (axis cs:4.6,7.0);
\coordinate (c4) at (axis cs:4.6,3);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\savebox\rightplot{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{axis}[axis equal image=true,xlabel={nb\_bump\_on\_decreasing\_sequence},
ylabel={nb\_decreasing},
title style={yshift=1.2ex},
title={$\argument{sv}=11$},
xtick ={0,2,...,3},
ytick ={0,2,...,11},
minor tick num=1,
grid=both,grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!20},
xmin=-1,xmax=3,
ymin=-1,ymax=11,
extra description/.code={
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description1) at (c1) {\large\ding{172}};
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description2) at (c2) {\large\ding{173}};
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description3) at (c3) {\large\ding{174}};
 \node[inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=white,circle] (description4) at (c4) {\large\ding{175}};
}]

\addplot[blue!20,only marks]
    coordinates {(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)(0,4)(0,5)(0,6)(0,7)(0,8)(0,9)(0,10)};
\addplot[blue!50,only marks]
    coordinates {(1,4)(1,5)(1,6)(1,7)(1,8)(1,9)(2,6)(2,7)(2,8)};
\addplot[red,only marks]
    coordinates {(1,3)};
\addplot[blue!50,densely dashed]
    coordinates {(0,0)(2,6)(2,8)(0,10)(0,0)(0,0)};
\draw[fill=pink,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:-1.5,-1) -- (axis cs:4.5,11) -- (axis cs:4.5,11) -- (axis cs:4.5,-1) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick]
    coordinates {(-1.5,-1)(4.5,11)};
\draw[fill=pink,opacity=0.1] (axis cs:-1,4) -- (axis cs:3,4) -- (axis cs:3,-1) -- (axis cs:-1,-1) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!20,thick]
    coordinates {(-1,4)(3,4)};
\draw[fill=cyan,opacity=0.2] (axis cs:-1,11.0) -- (axis cs:3,7.0) -- (axis cs:3,11) -- (axis cs:-1,11) -- cycle;
\addplot[black!50,thick]
    coordinates {(-1,11.0)(3,7.0)};
\addplot[orange]
    coordinates {(1,3)(3,3)};
\addplot[orange,only marks,mark=otimes*]
    coordinates {(1,3)};
\addplot[orange,only marks,mark=diamond*]
    coordinates {(2,3)};
\coordinate (c1) at (axis cs:3.55,8.0);
\coordinate (c2) at (axis cs:3.55,4);
\coordinate (c3) at (axis cs:3.55,7.0);
\coordinate (c4) at (axis cs:3.55,3);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (left plot){\usebox\leftplot};
\node[right=2cm of left plot.east,anchor=west] (right plot){\usebox\rightplot};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah! so we can nest them. :)  +1

Comment: Both examples work, but I don't manage to externalise the compilation of such figures. I will come back with some example showing the problem. Should I post the problem in this question (since it will be related to externalisation)?

Comment: It work for both figures, but I don't know how to externalise such tikzfigure with \sbox. I add in the post a small example how I externalise the compilation.

Comment: @NicolasBeldiceanu If you have additional information, please add it to _your_ question. Please refrain from trying to add it to other peoples answers.

Comment: Sorry I thought I was editing my question. So how to remove it from the current answer ?

Comment: `\def\argument` etc. is not safe, even though the nesting is.

Comment: @NicolasBeldiceanu See the manual re. externalisation. Was this part of your original question? If not, it should be a follow-up. When Ti*k*Z externalises, all other `tikzpicture`s are discarded. You can switch this off, I think, but it may result in longer compilation times, depending on the document.

Comment: @NicolasBeldiceanu It works if you switch it off. I made a minimal example to test.

Comment: Externalisation was part of the initial question, which explains the proposed answer of @marmot ; I don't understand what you mean by "if you switch IT off". Anyway the small example I gave in the post for externalising works (but not with the proposed solution up to now).  And the motivation of this question is that you can compile in parallel all your tikz figures (using a makefile with make -j 8):  when doing the first compilation, this avoids too long compilation time.

Comment: @NicolasBeldiceanu I was without internet and there is no way I can dig through all the conversations. Could you please provide me with a short summary of what you are asking, preferably in a short statement on the end of you question? (And internet is still shaky, so it may take a while till I respond.)

Comment: My short question is: how to insert my first fig of this post (the one with pink and cyan stuff) and my second fig of this post (the one with just pink stuff) using your proposed solution in fig1.tex and in fig2.tex and use the compilation process I proposed (which works for the current tiny figures in fig1.tex and fig2.tex).

Comment: @NicolasBeldiceanu Honestly, I don't know, I never use externalize. And frankly, I would consider this a separate question. Note also that your question is rather "old" now, and out of sight for those who are hunting new questions, so I really would recommend to ask a separate question. And please make use of `filecontents` such that the users have only to compile one MWE rather than creating several files.

Comment: @NicolasBeldiceanu Honestly, I don't know, I never use externalize. And frankly, I would consider this a separate question. Note also that your question is rather "old" now, and out of sight for those who are hunting new questions, so I really would recommend to ask a separate question. And please make use of `filecontents` such that the users have only to compile one MWE rather than creating several files.

Comment: I will ask another question later on, but there are two issues with posting such question: first I will need to provide 3 files (one of them containing your suggestion and I never used MWE). Second, I have to use your suggestion, since with simpler tikz figures the externalisation works fine (so this means the new question will still be related to this question)

Comment: @NicolasBeldiceanu There is nothing wrong with that. And I am sorry that I cannot help you with externalization issues.